# What is the middle name of George A. Grätzer?

Tags: mathematics, logicians

What is the middle name of [George A. Grätzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Gr%C3%A4tzer)?

Comment: For what it's worth, in my personal notes I have George [György] A. Grätzer (1936−____), so I haven't been able to determine his middle name either, although I suspect I haven't tried to find it in at least 2 or 3 years.

Comment: The title page of his Ph.D. thesis (1959) does not show a middle name: Grätzer György, Standard Ideálok. Have you tried contacting professor Grätzer? His email address can be found [here](http://www.algebrauniversalis.com/editorial-board), for example, and based on additional instances appears to have been stable for many years.

Comment: For what it's worth, Knuth, TAOCP, vol. 4A, lists him simply as: *Grätzer, György (= George)*